# Differentiating using multiple rules - spot my mistake

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to figure out my mistake here.

Find the Derivative of $$\frac {x^2}{x-1}$$
Now I want to simplify this and use the product rule instead of the quotient rule:
$$(x^2)(x-1)^{-1}$$
Use the product rule:
$$[\frac {d}{dx}x^2](x-1)^{-1}+[{\frac {d}{dx}(x-1)^{-1}]}(x^2)$$
Simplify left side:
$$\frac {2x}{x-1}$$
Simplify right side by using chain rule:
$$-(x-1)^{-2}(x^2)$$
$$-\frac {x^2}{(x-1)^2}$$
Add them all together, result:$$\frac {2x-x^2}{(x-1)-(x-1)^2}$$

The correct answer would have been:
$$\frac {x^2-2x}{(x-1)^2}$$

I'm pretty sure, would I've used the quotient rule, the result would've been the correct one. But why did this result in a wrong answer?
Thanks in advance for any clarity on the subject.

Comment: Why did you add the denominators?

Comment: You added the fractions wrong!

Comment: You need to get a common denominator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac {2x}{x-1}-\frac {x^2}{(x-1)^2}=\frac {2x(x-1)-x^2}{(x-1)^2}=\frac {x^2-2x}{(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: ^^ thanks gimusi!

Comment: @user472288 Just a simple arithmetic issue! You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

This line is not correct
$$\frac {2x-x^2}{(x-1)-(x-1)^2}$$
It should be
$$\frac {2x}{(x-1)}-\frac {x^2}{(x-1)^2}=\frac {2x(x-1)-x^2}{(x-1)^2}=\frac {x^2-2x}{(x-1)^2}$$